# How screen sharing works in Flutter? What I need?

Tags: flutter, webrtc, screensharing

what do I need for screen sharing in app in Flutter? I don't know how to get this sharing screen and show it in widget and I'm looking for the answer.

What steps should I take?

Comment: Are you talking about screen sharing from one app to other like microsoft teams or skype?
If yes .. check Enablex.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand the problem.
If you want to share something like file, link, image, you can use the flutter shared package.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_share

but if you want to share a redirect link within the application or a widget within the application if you want to make a redirect within this widget. If you want to go directly to that page, you should use a deep link. You need to know some information in deep link, I'm leaving a blog post to help you in it.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283

https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

https://blog.logrocket.com/understanding-deep-linking-flutter-uni-links/

I hope this article helped you.

Answer (score 1):

you should implement Webrtc signaling in your application.
you can read Webrtc Apis here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API

in the flutter, we have a package for Webrtc:
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc

instead of getUserMedia, you must use getDisplayMedia for screen sharing.